# How can I make a Tablix to show all the data from any dataset in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I wrote a data extension which returns a DataSet to a report from the the C# code by implementing

```
Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataProcessing.IDbConnection
```

Basing on the Dataset's parameters, **this 'Dataset' means the one in report design mode**,  my extension could return totally different structured DataTable, different column names, different number of columns etc, but the table's name is always the same.

My questions is:

**How can I have a Tablix in my report, and this Talix just show all the columns and rows in a very simple way?**

or

**Is this posible?**

Comment: make all your result sets return `Col1, Col2` etc...

Comment: A dataset is simply made of two things 1) Sql Server Query 2) Connection String .  Tablix(Table, Matrix, List) and defined on report design level. You need to create/Design report in SSRS and then use the url to call the report from your C# application or use ReportViewer to call the report from your application.

Answer (score 0):

Ha, I was joking when i said "make all your result sets return Col1, Col2 etc..." but apparently that is the way to do it.

[SQL Reporting Services with Dynamic Column Reports - Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11254/SQL-Reporting-Services-with-Dynamic-Column-Reports)

Comment: My table's column names are different from table to table,that seems not supporting this.

Comment: SSRS is specific about fields to the point of case sensitive, I have not come across anything that would suggest there is a one size fits all report.